# How do I clean ununsed tags from Finder?

Tags: finder, finder-tag

I seem to have accumulated a number of tags, some of which are duplicate and which do not belong to any files. I can see these tags when I open **All Tags**. These I assume were set for some files, which were then deleted.

How do I clean up the Finder so that only the current tags are present?

Answer (score 1):

Open Finder preferences either by going to `Finder → Preferences` in Menu bar or by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> keyboard shortcut with with Finder.app open.

Go to Tags tab, select the unwanted tags and hit `-` button.

[image]

Comment: I have a very large number of tags -- more than a hundred (I have been overzealous), and was hoping for a more automatic solution. This requires me to verify whether each tag has an associated file, and then delete that manually :(

Comment: @rahul I am looking for a better solution too. See if this helps you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334448/remove-unused-finder-tags