# Remove unused Finder tags

Tags: finder-tag

I make extensive use of Finder Tags, both built-in and user generated. I have ended up with a huge bunch of tags would like to better manage them.

Is there a way to easily visualize the count of files tagged with a particular tag? That way I can easily get rid of the **unused tags** (tags with zero associated files) which have accumulated in due course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view all the available tags in Finder, follow these steps:

1. Enable display of tags by going to `Finder → Preferences → Sidebar → Tags → Recent Tags`.

[image]

2. In the Finder menu, enable show **Sidebar** and **Status Bar** if they are hidden.
3. Under Tags section in the Finder Sidebar, click on `All Tags...`. This will display a list of all the available tags (pre-created + custom) sorted alphabetically.
4. Click to select a tag from the list. The count of files/folders associated with the tag is shown in the Status Bar.

[image]

5. To delete a tag, right click on it and select `Delete Tag "Tag_Name"...` from the context menu.

[image]

---

For more information on tags in Finder, refer to the Apple support document, [macOS Sierra: Use tags to organize files](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph25325).

Comment: I know this is offtopic, but I have a direct question to you: how did you change the background color of your finder windows?

Comment: @Garex Mojave dark mode :) Will be coming out in September or October.

Comment: thanks - so I need to look for a theming engine for high sierra. BTW that looks awesome good. :-D

Answer (score 2):

## Using Terminal

Given to a shell, this returns the count of files tagged with the tag named *Yellow*:

```
mdfind -count 'kMDItemUserTags = Yellow'
```